# couldn't show list of documents in the view using derbyjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, derbyjs, racerjs, isomorphic-javascript

It's my first time with derbyjs, don't know if i am being stupid or is it a lack of documentation.
i have a model called "books", and i am just trying to show list of books.

here is my code:

```
module.exports = {
    properties: {
        title: {type: 'string', minLength: 6},
        author: {type: 'integer', minimum: 0},
        image: {type: 'string'},
        status: {type: 'integer', minimum: 0, maximum: 1}, // 1 read, 0 wants to read
        comment: {type: 'string'}
    },
    required: ['title']
}
```

and the schema list

```
module.exports = {
    schemas: {
        auths: require('./model/auths'),
        products: require('./model/products'),
        books: require('./model/books')
    }
}
```

the index js

```
app.get('/shelf', function(page, model, params, next){
    model.subscribe('books', function(){
        var book = model.at('books.669374b5-8470-4f3a-a25f-0995a5a92a7a');
        model.ref('_page.book', book);
        page.render('home');
    });
});
```

i expect to have "books" in the view, so i wrote {{each}} like this

```
{{ each books as #b}}
    {{ #b.title }}
{{/each}}
```

but nothing shows up, although this works fine and render as expected

```
{{ _page.book.title }}
```

also at the web console, this works fine and shows 3 books

```
app.model.get('books')
```

notice: i added the books through the web console, something like this

```
app.model.add('books', {title: 'something'})
```

inside the subscribe function, i have tried to

```
var books = model.get('books');
model.ref('_page.books', books);
```

but an error rise up

any idea what i am doing wrong ? i really like derbyjs but this is holding me back for few days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like for the page to update automatically you should use a `ref` instead of a `get()` however, e.g.

```js
app.get('/shelf', function(page, model, params, next) {
  var booksQuery = model.query('books', {});
  model.subscribe(booksQuery, function(err) {
    booksQuery.ref('_page.books');
    page.render('books');
  });
});
```

Template:

```html
{{ each _page.books as #b}}
  {{ #b.title }}
{{/each}
```

In addition to the official Derby docs I've found the [derby-faq](https://github.com/derbyparty/derby-faq/tree/master/en) to be a good resource.

Comment: To explain this a bit more, `books` is a collection, and collections are represented as objects in the model. In Derby templates, `{{each}}` blocks can only iterate over arrays and *not* over objects. As Kyle pointed out, you can use a refList to create an array of documents in a collection corresponding to query results. Alternatively, you can use model.filter to map a collection into an array.

Comment: what i would like to ask, i always need to use subscribe before i use model.get() ? because the first method in the answer didn't work for me, but the second works fine.

Comment: Yes, you have to use subscribe to populate the model. Thanks for let me know about the error, I removed it so that others won't be confused.